# Access data from a jQuery ajax with callback response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I am building a Rails 5 app where I try to parse a response that I get back from a remote server.

The URL is:

```
https://sigtunahem.se/widgets/?callback=jQuery&widgets%5B%5D=objektsortering&widgets%5B%5D=objektfilter&widgets%5B%5D=objektlista%40lagenheter&widgets%5B%5D=pagineringgofirst&widgets%5B%5D=pagineringgonew&widgets%5B%5D=pagineringlista&widgets%5B%5D=pagineringgoold&widgets%5B%5D=pagineringgolast&widgets%5B%5D=paginering&_=1571006343035
```

The response is look somewhat like this (I tried to paste the full response but I passed the limit of 30000 characters here on Stackoverflow).

```
jQuery (
  {
    data": {
      "objektlista@lagenheter": [
        "objektNr": null,
        "platsNr": null,
        "adress": "Katt Anders gränd 4",
        "omrade": "Sigtuna"
      ]
    }
  }
)
```

How can I "get passed" the jQuery so I can access the information in the data object?

I am stuck.

Comment: That is a *JSONP* formatted response. Not entirely clear where you are having issues. Have you created a `$.ajax()` request to that endpoint?

Comment: No, I am using ruby / rails to parse this response not Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: The outer `jQuery()` is derived from whatever value is used in `callback` param. If it was `?callback=foo...` the response would be wrapped in `foo()`. So use a  regex to get the JSON string inside the callback wrapper. Using `$.ajax()` client side is simple also